# Update an XML document using Python or a shell script

Tags: python, bash, shell

I have an XML file that is used as index for a dynamic panel with this structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Addons>
  <line>
    <text>My collection 1</text>
    <level>3</level>
    <comment/>
    <file>Collection1.zip</file>
    <size>120</size>
    <parent>Collection</parent>
    <directory>picture</directory>
    <type>jpeg</type>
    <filedate>22/05/2014</filedate>
  </line>
  <line>
    <text>My collection 2</text>
    <level>3</level>
    <comment/>
    <file>Collection2.zip</file>
    <size>880</size>
    <parent>Collection</parent>
    <directory>picture</directory>
    <type>jpeg</type>
    <filedate>01/04/2013</filedate>
  </line>
</Addons>
```

My panel uses this file as building index. When I update the files on the server, I need to update the `filedate` element by hand, ...but the file has 80 lines and it's terrible.

Is there a way by a script to do the job?
The sequence is:

- parse the file line by line
- read the file name from the `<file>` element
- get the last-modification date of the file
- update the `<filedate>` element if present
- go to next line

Shell scripts and Python are available on the server.

Thanks!!

Comment: The proper tool would be an XML processor. Do you have `xsltproc` or similar?

Answer (score 2):

Using the [`xmlstarlet`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) command line tool:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//file' -n file.xml |
while IFS= read -r filename; do
    filedate=$(date -d "@$(stat -c %Y "$filename")" +%d/%m/%Y)
    xmlstarlet ed --inplace -u "//filedate[../file = '$filename']" -v "$filedate" file.xml
done
```

Comment: +1; delightfully concise; however, you probably meant `file.xml` instead of `xml.xml` in the 2nd `xmlstarlet` invocation; also, to get the `xmlstarlet sel` command (1st invocation) to terminate its output with `\n`, I had to insert option `-n` after `'//file'` - without it, `read` wouldn't pick up the last filename. Finally, a heads-up: implies use of _GNU_ `date` and `stat` (probably a fair assumption on a server). `xmlstarlet` can be found at http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @user3685289, I would highly recommend using the date format `%Y-%m-%d` -- anything else is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little python script that does that for you:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re
from datetime import date

input_file = open("input.xml", "r")
output_file = open("output.xml", "w")

today = date.today().strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
replacement = '<filedate>' + today + '</filedate>' 

for line in input_file:
    updated_line = re.sub(r'<filedate>.*?</filedate>', replacement, line)
    output_file.write(updated_line)

input_file.close()
output_file.close()
```

Comment: This works for the sample input file _as formatted_, but what if the `filedate` element is spread across multiple lines? Use of an XML processor avoids such issues.

Comment: Shure, this is not a general solution for xml parsing. But I think it does the job for the author. And why would you split such short information like a date into multiple lines?

Comment: SO is as much about the general as it is about the specific. If you're parsing a format that is not line-oriented line by line, it makes your solution _fragile_ (less general). If you decide to go with this approach (for a simpler, quicker solution), _its limitations are worth noting_ - which is what I did in my comment, but doing so in your answer is preferable. Also note that your solution is not retrieving the last-modified time stamp from the files referenced (another thing worth mentioning, if you decide not to implement that part).

Answer (score 0):

A **Python** solution that uses an **XML parser** (`xml.etree`) to robustly process the input:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import datetime
from xml.etree import ElementTree

inFile = "in.xml"
outFile = "out.xml"

# Parse the entire document.
tree = ElementTree.parse(inFile)

# Loop over the <line> elements
for elem in tree.iter('line'):

  # Get the child element [values] of interest.
  fname = elem.find('file').text.strip()
  elemFDate = elem.find('filedate')

  # Determine the new modification date.
  # Note: As @glenn jackman notes, %Y-%m-%d would be a better date format to use.
  newDate = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(fname)) \
    .strftime("%d/%m/%y")

  # Update the date element.
  elemFDate.text = newDate


# Write the output file.
tree.write(outFile)
```

Note:

- The entire document is read and written at once, which is only appropriate for smaller XML files.
- There is no error handling - all relevant elements and the files referenced are assumed to exist.